# How to get html response from middleware UseDeveloperExceptionPage in statup (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exception, httpresponse, exceptionfilterattribute

**How to read HTML response from well-formatted HTML response by built-in and generated from UseDeveloperExceptionPage in startup class** when a generic exception is thrown. so that I can send the same exception as email body just like Elmah logging sends exception via email.

Please follow the code below:

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage

Only way is to re-do the html construction using a reference from original source code.